# insertRowsAtIndexPathsでセルが挿入されない

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

現在スイッチを押すと`TableView`のセルを一行挿入する処理を行おうとしているのですが、下記のコードだと挿入されません。
試しに`if`を抜けた後に`[self.tableView reloadData];`を入れて実行すると、スイッチを押した後にセルが挿入されるようになるのですが、アニメーションもなくてカクカクした動きになっています。なので`insertRowsAtIndexPaths`を使ってセルの挿入を行いたいのですが、なぜ挿入されないのでしょうか？`reloadData`が実行されるとセルが挿入されるということは、挿入の処理は正しく行えており、アニメーションがうまく行えていないということなのでしょうか...？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
if (sw.on) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];

        [identifierInSection2 addObject:@"pickerCell"];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    } else {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];

        [identifierInSection2 removeLastObject];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: 一見して、テーブル表示のデータである配列への挿入位置、削除位置と、テーブルの挿入行、削除行が一致していないようですが？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。deleteRowAtIndexPathsのindexPathForRowを1にしたところ、スイッチが切り替わるごとにフェードしながらセルが追加されたり削除したりできるようになったのですが、なぜか一回目にスイッチをオンにした時だけセルが追加されません。2回目以降は正常に動きます。一体なぜなのでしょうか？

Comment: 「一体なぜ」と訊かれても、あなたがやってはいけないことをやってるからと、答えるしかないと思いますよ。たとえば、総行数10行のテーブルの、15行目に挿入するとか、18行目を削除するとか、そういうことは、まちがいなくやってはいけないことですよね？

Comment: 先ほどから考えているのですが、やってはいけないことをやっている感覚がありません。僕が現在考えているのは、セクションの一番上に表示されてるセルの下にセルを挿入するのにまずindexPathForRowに1を指定し、そしてinsertRowAtIndexPathsを行ってやれば一番上のセルの下にセルが挿入されるのではないか？ということです。ということはindexPathの数え方が違うのでしょうか？そして1回目だけができなくて2回目以降ができるという意味がわかりません。なぜ何の処理も変えていないにも関わらず2回目以降できるようになるのかが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「挿入」ボタンを押すと、テーブルの2行目に行を挿入し、「削除」ボタンを押すと、テーブルの2行目を削除するプログラムを作ってみました。
テーブルに表示するデータであるNSMutableArray「dataArray」は、挿入時、2番目にアイテムを挿入し、削除時、2番目のアイテムを削除しています。ここがあなたのプログラムと異なるところですかね？
なんの異常もなく動作することを確認のうえ、掲載しております。参考になさってください。

*ViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataArray = [@[@"Line 0"] mutableCopy];
}

- (IBAction)editTable:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender { // ツールバーに、「挿入」、「削除」ボタンアイテムを設置してある。
    if (sender.tag == 10) { // 挿入のボタンのtagが10
        NSString *newLine = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Line %ld", self.dataArray.count];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 1 inSection: 0];
        [self.dataArray insertObject: newLine atIndex: 1];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: @[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    } else { // 削除ボタンの処理
        if (self.dataArray.count > 1) { // テーブルの行数が1行なら、それ以上削除しない。
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 1 inSection: 0];
            [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex: 1];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
    }
}

// Table View Delegate and DataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: サンプルでご説明頂き、誠にありがとうございます。自分の手元で動かしたところ、自分の行いたい動作をしていたのでぜひこちらを参考にさせていただきたいと思います。ありがとうございます。